# How to restore a deleted organization(created in GitHub)?

Tags: github, restore, organization

I have wrongly deleted organization (created in GitHub). How to restore the deleted organization? I have access to my GitHub profile.

Comment: Have you tried the instructions provided on [official GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/admin/user-management/managing-organizations-in-your-enterprise/restoring-a-deleted-organization)?

Comment: Hi @MaitreyC, i have paid Github Organization Account. But when i tried to access GitHub Enterprise with option "Sign in via GitHub". But it is asking to create account or contact sales team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do not have an GitHub Enterprise Server license, you cannot restore the organization, as written in the delete section of an organization:

> Once deleted, it will be gone forever. Please be certain.

If you do have an GitHub Enterprise Server license, you can follow the official documentation [*Restoring a deleted organization*](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/admin/user-management/managing-organizations-in-your-enterprise/restoring-a-deleted-organization).

Comment: Hi @tjarbo, i have paid Github Organization account. But when i tried to access GitHub Enterprise with option "Sign in via GitHub". But it is asking to create account or contact sales team

Comment: Hi @Pabal, you would know if you have a GitHub Enterprise license. A paid GitHub organization in the "Team" tier is something else. See the official https://github.com/pricing page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/9990990/tjarbo is correct. We connected with the Sales Team of Github and got the subscription money refunded. That is the only way.